# I encountered an error after running the code: ( sumation = sum(var.copy()) TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, types, while-loop

I couldnt recognize my problem with `sum(var.copy())`. Lasty Edited 11:33 07.02.2021

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
f_ext_ele_groups= [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5], [6,6], [7,7], [8,8], [9,9], [10,10]]
                          
front_design_array=[]          
length=len(f_ext_ele_groups)    
while length > 0:               
    
    for var in f_ext_ele_groups:
        
        sumation=sum(var.copy())

    if sumation ==10:
        front_design_array.append(var)

    elif sumation < 10:
        draft= []
        for ele in array:
            if int(var[0]+ ele) <= 10:
                draft.append([var[0], ele])
            else:
                continue
        f_ext_ele_groups.append(draft)

    length=len(f_ext_ele_groups)
```

Comment: In `sumation += x[:]` you are trying to copy the values of an array `x` and add it to `sumation` but `x` is a number and not an array.

Comment: I tried ' sumation += x ' but it returned the same error

Comment: I ran the code and got `summation = 55`. Please format the question and include what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: first while loop iterates the remained code. f_ext_ele_groups is refreshed in every iteration. For example, after first iteration, f_ext_ele_groups= [[1,1],[1,2].....[1,9],[2,1],[2,2],..[2,9]....[9,1]],  and also,  front_design_array=[[10]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yudhiesh answered your question, but here is how you ended up where you did.

You start with a list of lists where each inner list contains a single int.

```
f_ext_ele_groups= [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

You then use `var` to iterate over the lists in `f_ext_ele_groups` -> [1]

```
for var in f_ext_ele_groups:
```

You then use `x` to iterate over the int in `var` -> 1

```
for x in var:
```

Lastly, you try subscript `x`, but `x` is an int.

```
sumation += x[:]
```

Comment: I edited my question. May you check it again?

Comment: Now, edited again. Sorry for sequential actions.